# force database update to fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

I am testing a controller and would like to force a db update to fail in order to verify that my error handling is working properly. I am fairly new to rails so I apologize if I am not following all of the best practices. Below is the relevant code:

*Code is not complete as to focus on the important parts relevant to this question.*

**Controller:**

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController

  ...

  # relevant actions
  def enable
    able true
  end

  def disable
    able false
  end

  ...

  private 

  def able (b)
    ...
    # @dbobject will be set in a 'before_filter' function
    if @dbobject.update_attribute(enabled: b)
      # do some stuff
    else # <------ need to force execution of this block
      # error handling, logging, boring stuff
      redirect_to @dbobject
    ...
  end

  ...

end
```

**Test:**

```
class SomeController::AbleTest < ActionController::TestCase
  tests SomeController

  setup
    # create @dbobject
  end

  test 'redirect occurs on update fail' do
    get :enable, id: @dbobject
    assert_redirected_to @dbobject
  end 

  ...

end
```

I also have tests in `SomeController::AbleTest` that require `update_attribute` to work properly so I would prefer to stay away from overriding the method completely. Is there any way to force the db to raise an exception if this record is accessed or something similar? I am not able to call the `able` method directly from the test class because it relies heavily on instance variables set by various `before_filter` methods and it feels too much like fighting the framework to not make the `get :enable` and have these methods run automatically.

Comment: it would be useful to see the before filter that sets the instance variable

Comment: Generally you trip errors like this by deliberately submitting invalid data for your update. For example, if a name property needs to be a minimum of four letters, send in an empty string. I encourage using the pattern of `update_attributes!(...)` which throws an exception, and then having a `rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` to recover from that. There are possibly other exceptions like `ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved` if it's possible for one of your `before_save` filters to cancel the save, but that's usually rare.

Comment: @Yule I am forced to not post the entire set of code but the relevant information from the before filter is simply like this: `@dbobject = DBObject.find(params[id'])`

Comment: @tadman I can't force invalid form data because the only attribute being updated in the boolean value passed as an argument to the `able` function directly from the `enable` and `disable` actions.

Comment: @tadman and I am trying to stick to unit testing only via the public API of the controller, without diving in to setting my own context and calling private functions.

Comment: @steve Exactly why I'm saying if you can trigger that `else` by throwing in bad data, do it that way.

Comment: @tadman where would I have the access to throw in bad data? the only two values ever passed to `able` are `true/false` coming directly from the two relevant actions. These are hardcoded values the `enable/disable` actions do not read from params or anything similar.

Comment: It seems there is no way that the else branch of your code will ever be executed. Delete that code, then there is no need to test it. The correct thing to do if saving fails would be to raise an exception, which can be done by replacing `update_attribute` with `update_attribute!`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use stubs. Look into [mocha](https://github.com/freerange/mocha):

```
DBObject.any_instance.stubs(:update_attribute).returns(false)
```

This would mean whenever you can update_attribute on any instance of DBObject, it would return false, sending you into the else. So teh whole code would be:

```
 test 'redirect occurs on update fail' do
    DBObject.any_instance.stubs(:update_attribute).returns(false)
    get :enable, id: @dbobject
    assert_redirected_to @dbobject
  end
```

Comment: Will this override the `update_attribute` method for all instances in other test blocks as well? I am relying on the method to function properly in other tests and only need it to return false in this one test.

Comment: No, it'll be just scoped to this test

Comment: Works like a charm! You saved me a few more hours of searching.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [mocha](https://rubygems.org/gems/mocha) gem. You can temporarily stub `update_attributes` so it returns `false`.

```
dbobject.stubs(:update_attributes).returns(false)
```

Note that `dbobject` isn't the same as the `@dbobject` you're passing to `get` in your test. You'll have to stub the code that fetches the record in your controller. This is more troublesome than Yule's way of `any_instance`, so try that first.

Comment: I have tried a similar solution where I manually redefined the `update_attribute` method on the `@dbobject` inside my test class, but because I am only passing the `id` to the controller, the same instance is not used (because it does another db.find) and the method returns to the original as declared by the class.

Comment: I recommend against redefining methods yourself, because if you don't revert the change correctly, you could get false negatives & positives for the rest of the tests.

Comment: that's exactly what I was running into and was hoping there was a better way. It looks like @Yule's addition of `any_instance` is exactly what I need to get mocha to work for me. thank you for the help.